# How to I customise the values on the Y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 in R to create a histogram and I would like to customise the values on the y axis. At present the values on the Y axis range from one and have an interval of 3. I would like to make all the values on the on the y axis visible i.e. 1,2,3 and so on.

How do I do this?

```
plot_2 <-
 ggplot(Tennis, aes(x=winner)) + 
        geom_bar(data = subset(top_wins, tournament == "French Open")) +
        ggtitle("French Open")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scale_y_continuous() function. Below is an example where the y axis will go from 0 to 20.

```
ggplot() + geom_point(data = iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Petal.Length,color = Species)) +
  + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 20), breaks = seq(0, 20, by = 1)
```